# installing tensorflow on ubuntu linux, protobuf version issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-console

While installing tensorflow on Ubuntu (GCloud VM), I am getting alert as -

```
pip install tensorflow
```

apache-beam 0.6.0 has requirement protobuf==3.2.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.5.2 which is incompatible.

2. when I try to upgrade apache-beam. It is giving error -

   pip install apache-beam

tensorflow-tensorboard 0.4.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.4.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.2.0 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 1.7.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.4.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.2.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 1.4.1 has requirement protobuf>=3.3.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.2.0 which is incompatible.
grpcio 1.11.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.5.0.post1, but you'll have protobuf 3.2.0 which is incompatible.

3. When directly upgrading the protobuf version -

   pip install protobuf==3.5.2

apache-beam 0.6.0 has requirement protobuf==3.2.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.5.2 which is incompatible.

Don't know how to resolve this interdependency.

```
uname -a
```

16-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

You could reference this [dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile) for installing tensorflow as python package.
After you succeed, then try install apache-beam.